# Unable to scan and collect Entity.class annotated classes using FastClasspathScanner

Tags: java, annotations, javers

I am using fast-classpath-scanner (v2.18.1 as part of [Javers](https://javers.org/))

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.github.lukehutch</groupId>
 <artifactId>fast-classpath-scanner</artifactId>
 <version>2.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and I trying to scan a specific folder in my classpath for getting all the classes annotated with

```
@Entity
```

my code given here is using Javers utility class

```
ReflectionUtil.findClasses(Entity.class, "my.model");
```

or

```
new FastClasspathScanner("my.model").scan().getNamesOfClassesWithAnnotation(Entity.class)
```

In both cases the above snippets return an empty Collection.

Is there some special trick to make this play as expected and scan those @Entity annotated classes?

Comment: if you think you found a bug, please report an issue to javers or fast-classpath-scanner? providing a runnable test case with reproduction scenario

Comment: I have just tried to isolate it from home in a non-OSGI set up and ReflectionUtil.findClasses(Entity.class, "my.model") works fine and returns the expected Entity classes, so no issue with javers/fast-classpath-scanner. It must be something to do with the classloader in the OSGI set up and with how fast-classpath-scanner scans. Thanks anyway!